# Cannot Connect to Sql Server Express localhost Classic ASP

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I have scoured the internet for a reason why I can't connect to SQL Server Express 2008 R2, Sql Authentication Mode with the following conn string:

```
DBConn = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Data Source=TURTLE_BRAIN\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ssgroup_dbuser;User Id=dbuser;Password=dbuser1"

Sub OpenConn()

 Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.connection")

Conn.CursorLocation = adUseClient

Conn.Open DBConn

End Sub
```

And I have also tried provider:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI10
```

And provider:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI11
```

And, in place of `User Id=dbuser;` I have tried:

```
Uid=db_user;
```

I have had hours of issues using Windows Authentication too. So I thought I would focus on Sql Authentication mode instead as I see it to be simpler and isolate issues such as Windows Authentication/Impersonation and what my ApplicationPool account might be.

dbuser is a db_owner for database: `ssgroup_dbuser`

I am getting the error:

```
Server error '80004005'

Cannot open database "ssgroup_dbuser" requested by the login. The login failed.
```

Comment: Could you show the code that use that connection string and try to open the connection?

Comment: Hi Steve, I had added the code that opens the connection, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this provided for SQL Server R2 is: Provider=SQLNCLI10.1

Also, can you login from your ASP page to SQL Server by using SA username/password?

I suppose your SQL user don't have Login rights. Can you login to SQL Server Management Studio and access your database by using your username/password?